# Does Mathematica have a problem with sums involving Stirling numbers of the second kind?

Tags: special-functions, summation

In one of my calculations, I run the command:

```
Sum[(StirlingS2[k - 1, 4] + StirlingS2[k, 4])/6^k, {k, Infinity}]
```

Surprisingly, `Mathematica` (run on Wolfram Cloud) does not want to perform this very simple summation, returning the definition of the command.

Even more surprisingly, the function starts returning numerical result if the argument of the first `StirlingS2` is changed from `k - 1` to `k`, but it processes the summation still incredibly long (it is just a sum of eight geometric series!).

What is the reason for the problem?

Comment: `ListPlot[Table[Sum[(StirlingS2[k-1,4]+StirlingS2[k,4])/6^k,{k,2,j}],{j,2,32}]]` strongly hints what the sum out to Infinity might be, unless you need some astonishing precision. Whether you start from 1 to j or 2 to j doesn't seem to make any obvious difference. So maybe the algorithm is fast for modest upper bounds and far slower for Infinite bounds. And maybe an infinite summation isn't as simple as you imagine it to be.

Comment: You should avoid using the bugs tag until your issue is confirmed to be a bug by the community. Simply returning the input probably means that Mathematica doesn't know the answer rather than it encountering some kind of bug.

Comment: @Bill Possibly I overestimate Mathematica. For me the result $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$ does not require long computation. Probably Mathematica does not recognize the sum. And the reason for the problem with the lower limit I cannot even guess.

Comment: I would appreciate if the downvoters communicate what they don't like in my question so that I could improve it.

Comment: Index shifting leads to joy: `Sum[(StirlingS2[k, 4] + StirlingS2[k + 1, 4])/6^(k + 1), {k, 0, ∞}]`

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

As you indicated, the problematic term is the one with `StirlingS2[k-1, 4]`

```
sum1 = Sum[#, {k, 1, Infinity}] & /@ 
  Expand[(StirlingS2[k - 1, 4] + StirlingS2[k, 4])/6^k]
```

[image]

Translate the index,

```
eqn1 = Inactive[Sum][StirlingS2[k - 1, 4]/6^k, {k, 1, Infinity}] == 
  Inactive[Sum][StirlingS2[k, 4]/6^(k + 1), {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image]

```
sum2 = eqn1[[-1]] // Activate

(* 1/720 *)
```

Adding the partial sums,

```
sum = sum1[[1]] + sum2

(* 7/720 *)
```

Checking numerically,

```
NSum[(StirlingS2[k - 1, 4] + StirlingS2[k, 4])/6^k, {k, 1, Infinity}] // 
  RootApproximant // Quiet

(* 7/720 *)
```

**EDIT:** Timing

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$HistoryLength = 0;

Sum[StirlingS2[k, 4]/6^k, {k, Infinity}] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.00014183, 1/120} *)

Sum[(StirlingS2[k, 4] + StirlingS2[k, 4])/6^k, {k, 
   Infinity}] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.000171701, 1/60} *)
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: For whatever reason, Mathematica does not have a pattern rule that matches `StirlingS2[k - 1, 4]` and it returns unevaluated. Manual intervention is needed to enable it to find a matching pattern.

Comment: Can you clarify why  the computation of the sum involving two Stirling numbers is several orders of magnitude slower than that involving a single number?

Comment: You don't say which two sums you are comparing so I have no way of guessing. If the sum with two Stirling numbers includes one that doesn't evaluate to a closed form, then I would assume that a lot of time is spent unsuccessfully trying transformations in an effort to find a closed form.

Comment: I indicated in my question that the "test" was performed after I replaced $k-1$ with $k$ in the first term. So they both were evaluated. And I compared the timing with the sum involving one of the both terms. It was several orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: I added timing. My results apparently differ radically from yours.

Comment: I think it is somehow connected with the system cache. The first calculation takes several orders of magnitude more time than the subsequent computation of the same expression: `Sum[StirlingS2[k,4]/7^k,{k,Infinity}]//AbsoluteTiming` -> `{2.2555}`.